# Exchange EWS ItemClass values

Tags: exchangewebservices

I searched a lot, but I was not able to find the common text values which the [ItemClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa580993%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) type can take.

I am aware of the fact that there can be custom values (like `IPM.Note.Custom.MyClass`), but are common values like `IPM.Note`, `IPM.Contact`, etc. documented somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Item Types** and **Message Classes** are [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861573.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing.  SilverNinjas link doesn't work anymore.

I found it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176446%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: I updated the link for **Office 2013**...thanks for notifying us!